React custom hook that incorporates event.preventDefault()
I am attempting to build React custom hooks store in an external file in order to clean up a React component that has gotten very long with many defined functions inside of it. Each hook is then imported into my React component.
I've built one successfully so far following the React custom hooks documentation, but I can't seem to get the second one to work.
The first one is as follows:
export function handleShowChange(){
    name => (e) =>{
        const [show, setShow] = useState('');
        useEffect(()=>{
            setShow(e.target.value);
        }, []);
        return show;
    };
};

This one works properly.
Following that form, I've built the second one as follows:
export function handleShowSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('Level 1');
    (e) =>{
        console.log('Level 2');
        const [showData, setShowData] = useState([]);
        useEffect(async ()=>{
            console.log('Level 3');
            const searchValue = e.target[0].value;
            try{
                const returnedData = await axios.get(`https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=${searchValue}`);
                console.log('Show search data from tvmaze API', returnedData);
                setShowData(returnedData.data);
                suggestionBoxWrapper.style.display='block';
            }catch(err){
                console.log(err);
            };
        }, []);
        return showData;
    };
};

The second one does not work. It runs up to and including the console.log('Level 1') statement, then stops there.
If I use the same basic code within the React component, written as:
    const handleShowSubmit = async (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        const searchValue = e.target[0].value;
        try{
            const returnedData = await axios.get(`https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=${searchValue}`);
            setShowData(returnedData.data);
            suggestionBoxWrapper.style.display='block';
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err);
        };
    };

it works correctly.
I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong with this second hook. I have read through the React custom hook documentation several times now and have searched and read several StackOverflow posts about React custom hooks, but I'm still at a loss.
How can I structure the custom hook so that it will work correctly within the React component?

These are pretty strange pieces of code. You say the first one works; can you show how you use it in a component? It looks to me like it's a function which creates (but does not return) a 2nd function which creates and returns a 3rd function. That 3rd function is a hook (since it calls other hooks), but i don't see how it could be called during rendering.

I don't see how your first code could work. If you call handleShowChange(), it will create a function internally, but that function is not called or returned so it has no effect. It also seems to misunderstand how hooks are supposed to be used, because the inner part ((e) => // etc) looks like an event callback. If so, that would be called outside of rendering, and hooks such as useState and useEffect can only be called during rendering.
Since the first code won't work, attempting to mimic it on the second code isn't going to work either

If I use the same basic code within the React component, written as:
const handleShowSubmit = async (e) => {
 e.preventDefault();
 const searchValue = e.target[0].value;
 try {
   const returnedData = await axios.get(
     `https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=${searchValue}`,
   );
   setShowData(returnedData.data);
   suggestionBoxWrapper.style.display = "block";
 } catch (err) {
   console.log(err);
 }
};

it works correctly.

Other than the direct manipulation of the dom, that looks like a pretty normal way to do it. In most cases i would leave it within the react component. If you do want to extract it into a custom hook (eg, to make the code reusable by multiple components, or if you feel it improves readability), that's mostly done via cut and paste.
Take your working handleShowSubmit and its associated state and paste it into a new function. Name that function starting with use to make clear it's a hook and thus needs to follow the rules of hooks. And return whatever is needed by the component.
For example:
const useHandleShowSubmit = () => {
  const [showData, setShowData] = useState([])
  const handleShowSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const searchValue = e.target[0].value;
    try {
      const returnedData = await axios.get(
        `https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=${searchValue}`,
      );
      setShowData(returnedData.data);
      suggestionBoxWrapper.style.display = "block";
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  return { showData, handleShowSubmit }
}

// used like:
const SomeComponent = () => {
  const { showData, handleShowSubmit } = useHandleShowSubmit()

  return (
    <div>
       {/* do something with showData */}
       <button onClick={handleShowSubmit}/>
    </div>
  );
}

